# How to read text file and show content in textarea with Django python?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django application. And I can upload files. But now I want to show the text from a text file in a text area.

So I have this:

forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    upload_file = forms.FileField()
```

models.py:

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images")
```

vieuws.py:

```
class CreateProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])
            uploadfile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": submitted_form
        })
```

and the html file:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Create a Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "main/styles/styles.css" %}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
      <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
    </form>   

    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have this textfile: yes.txt with this content: Yes, we can.

So my question is how to output this text in the textarea?

Comment: Do you have this `image` folder inside `media` folder which you define in `UploadFile` model?

Comment: I have the images folder in the uploads folder: MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "uploads" in the settins.py file

Comment: can you share settings.py for media?

Comment: You mean this: MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "uploads"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using messages which appear only one-time as notifications, use in following way instead.

views.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
import os


class CreateProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        content = ''

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])
            uploadfile.save()
            with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                   f"{uploadfile.image}"), 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()

            print(content)
            return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
                'form': ProfileForm(),
                "content": content
            })

        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": submitted_form,
        })
```

main/create_profile.html:

```html
<form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
</form>   
{% if content %}
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{content}}</textarea>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But what do you mean exactly with this sentence: "Without using messages which appear only one time,"

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Messages framework works only as an notification, the message appears only one time and after refreshing the page the message got destroyed.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton An excerpt from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/messages/) about messages. *Quite commonly in web applications, you need to display a one-time notification message (also known as “flash message”) to the user after processing a form or some other types of user input.*

Answer (score 1):

You could get the text of the uploaded file in the view and add it as a message (**don't forget to import messages from django.contrib in the views.py file**) and afterwards display it inside the textarea. My code looks like the following and works.

**views.py**

```
    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(my_file=request.FILES["upload_file"])
            uploadfile.save()
            # Get the text of the file of the instance
            with open(uploadfile.my_file.path) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            # Add the text as message
            messages.add_message(request, message=lines, level=messages.INFO)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        return render(request, "create_profile.html", {
        "form": submitted_form
        })
```

**template.html***

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Create a Profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "main/styles/styles.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Upload!</button>
</form>
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message %}
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" >{{ message }}</textarea>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oke, I will look at it. Thank you. But I have a more general question. Because now I have a method that filters some text from the tex file. And then I want to show to filtered text in the textarea. I just don't understand that if google for it, there is almost no information to find about it. I mean I thought this is just someting standard procedure. Because I have a 'console' application in python. And then in the terminal I can show the filtered text in the terminal. But I google for "show text from textfile in textfield with Django"  I can't find anything to archive this. Just my thoughts